# How to vertically centre tabs inside tab bar in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I've created a navigator in react native using `createBottomTabNavigator` from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to vertically centre the tabs inside the tab bar.

As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejiSJ.png) there is always that blue area at the bottom of the tabs. Even when I manually set the height for the tabs, they grow upward. If I set `flex:1` for the tab bar, it takes half of the screen, but the blue area still exists.

```
tabBar: {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  borderWidth: 2,
  height: 32,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: 0
},
labelStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'green',
},
tabStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: 'black',
  marginBottom: 0,
  paddingBottom: 0,
},
```

and this is how I create the nav bar (I removed the icons for simplicity):

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    screen1: { screen: screen1 },
    screen2: { screen: screen2 },
    screen3: { screen: screen3 },
    screen4: { screen: screen4 },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: styles.tabBar,
      labelStyle: styles.labelStyle,
      tabStyle: styles.tabStyle
    },
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default () => { 
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <App />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution myself and I'm sharing it for people who have the same problem. The reason the bottom spacing is always there is because of a prop called `safeAreaInset` and its default value is `{ bottom: 'always', top: 'never' }`

All I had to do was to change the value for `bottom` to `never` and it won't add any spacing to the bottom!

Answer (score 4):

This is due to icon component present above label. To hide icon component i added follow code.

```
tabBarOptions: {
  tabStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  showIcon: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting for v 6.x

`tabBarStyle:{ paddingBottom: 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

If you not showing icon add `{position: 'absolute', textAlignVertical: 'center'}` in label style, example:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
      tabBarIconStyle: {display: 'none'},
      tabBarStyle: {
        height: 40,
      },
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        position: 'absolute',
        textAlignVertical: 'center',
      },  
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap the tab bar in a view and add justifyContent there

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking about it, but the question is how? All I have is `const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Dashboard"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: true,
        tabBarStyle: styles.tabBar,
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 42,//edit this relative to your icon
        },
      }}
    >
```